# What Did Users Do or Use Before the Make Command?

Tags: compiling, gentoo, make, lfs

I use Gentoo as my primary home Desktop OS.  I have since ~2004.  I appreciate the `emerge` command for managing a source based OS as well as it does.  Every now and then I check on other distributions, but I'm particularly fond of [Linux From Scratch - For those of you Who Don't Know](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/).  Granted, I've never been through the entire book because using Gentoo has spoiled me in that respect.  I consider Gentoo to be LFS + a Package Manager.  I finally decided I'm going to complete the book, so I stuck XUbuntu on a VM to simulate the newness and ...

---

I'm following along in the release candidate for [Version 3 - Systemd of CLFS](http://trac.cross-lfs.org/wiki/read#ReadtheCrossLinuxFromScratchBookOnline), and it hit me at [Chapter 6 - Temporary System - Make](http://www.cross-lfs.org/view/CLFS-3.0.0-RC1-SYSTEMD/x86_64/temp-system/make.html).  *If a user needs `make` to compile a version of Make, the [Chicken and Egg Causality Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicken_or_the_egg) appears*  This leads me to my next logical questions.

1. **When [Stuart Feldman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stuart_Feldman) created `make` in 1976, how did the computing public compile his program if their OS did not contain an OS depenent `make`?  Am I to assume that the WikiPedia article below is true for every OS?**
2. **Did he have to package make to include every OS dependent version of make to complete 1?**(See Below)
3. **If I needed Program A, but it was only available to compile on OS A, did I have to buy OS A, even if I use OS B?**  (Please Ignore
   Windows here if Possible.)

**Update**

4. Based on jimmij's comment, **Did OS specific compilers exist in the same way that make was OS Dependent?**

[WikiPedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software)) says:

> Before Make's introduction, the Unix build system most commonly
>   consisted of operating system dependent "make" and "install" shell
>   scripts accompanying their program's source. Being able to combine the
>   commands for the different targets into a single file and being able
>   to abstract out dependency tracking and archive handling was an
>   important step in the direction of modern build environments.

Also, please note that I am looking for some historical perspective here, as I was born in 1976.

Comment: What you pasted from wikipedia answers your question: there was a shell script to "make" the program.

Comment: @psusi then I'll edit it, as WikiPedia only partly answers #1, which is why I asked it.  See Edited Q1

Comment: There's an underlying question inside your question.  You could also ask "If I need GCC to compile GCC, how did GCC ever spread?" or "If I need GCC to compile GCC, how did they get GCC 0.9, in order to compile GCC 1.0?" and maybe the answer has different details, but illustrates the same principle. T-diagrams or Tombstone diagrams can be used to illustrate this general principle: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tombstone_diagram

Comment: Needing `make` to make `make` is not an XY problem. That's a chicken & egg problem.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "every OS" nor "OS dependent version of make".  The program compiled on any unix the same way.  I also have no idea what you are asking in the third question.

Comment: @BruceEdiger You are correct in that respect, but since make-4.0 was the first package I ran into that I noticed the issue.  If we assume that `make` existed before gcc-0.9, we've answered the question.

Comment: @Patrick At the time I wrote this down in my head, I had no link here for Chicken and egg, another edit forthcoming

Comment: @psusi If every OS had a dependent version of Make and you used Program A that told you the Sky was Blue and I had Program B that told me the Grass was Green, how am I supposed to obtain your Program A for my OS B, if the 2 versions of `make' are incompatible?  Do I have to buy OS A, even though I use OS B, even though I only need OS A for Program A?

Comment: More generally, programs get ported to new environments with the help of _cross-compilers_: Compilers (and other tools) that generate object code suitable for a system other than their own.

Comment: I believe you probably wanted to ask more general question: `How people compiled programs before compilators (like gcc) existed?`. It would be quite interesting answer about bootstrapping etc.

Comment: You could look at DEC's VMS OS and its ecology. I'm pretty sure that VMS didn't have a standard build tool until MMS (http://h71000.www7.hp.com/doc/73final/5825/5825_idx.htm) which if I recall correctly arrived in the early 90s, 10 or 12 years after VMS was introduced.

Comment: @jimmij   Ooooh Should I add that Question???

Comment: @jimmij Added See Q4

Comment: Good, but I won't answer, I'm really not good at writing essays + it would be quite time consuming task. I willingly read others answer though. There is some article on wikipedia to start from: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping#Software_development

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make is simply for convenience. You can build software without it, it is just more difficult.

When you run `make` to build something, it shows you the commands it is running. You can run those commands manually and get the same effect.

```
$ echo "int main() {}" > test.c
$ make test
cc     test.c   -o test
```

Which created a file called `test`.
I can get the same result by just doing:

```
cc test.c -o test
```

If make didn't exist, you could either instruct users to run this `cc` command by hand, or you could distribute a shell script, and instruct them to run the script.